# one to many non mutual

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've got a problem with a many-to-one / one-to-many relationship with menu.cfc and menuItem.cfc. Both of them extends node.cfc (declarations of these at the end).

**index.cfm**

```
<cfset oMenu = entityNew( "menu" )>
<cfset oMenu.setTitle( "Main menu" )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenu )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfset oMenuItem = entityNew( "menuItem" )>
<cfset oMenuItem.setTitle( "First main menu item" )>
<cfset oMenuItem.setMenu( oMenu )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenuItem )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfdump var="#oMenu.getMenuItems()#">
<!--- array[empty] --->
<!--- WHY ?--->
```

In the DB, my menu_item.menu_id is correct.

I also tried

```
<cfset oMenu = entityNew( "menu" )>
<cfset oMenu.setTitle( "Main menu" )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenu )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfset oMenuItem = entityNew( "menuItem" )>
<cfset oMenuItem.setTitle( "First main menu item" )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenuItem )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfset oMenu.addMenuItem( oMenuItem )>

<cfdump var="#oMenu.getMenuItems()#">
<!--- array[empty] --->
```

In the DB, my menu_item.menu_id is null!

If you have an idea of what I did wrong, It will be nice.
Thanks!

**node.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent entityname="node" output="false" persistent="true" table="nodes" discriminatorcolumn="type">
    <cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" default="0" unsavedvalue="0">
    <cfproperty name="type" insert="false" update="false">
    <cfproperty name="title" ormtype="string" notnull="true" default="" loadInForm="true" required="true">
    <cfproperty name="systemName" column="system_name" ormtype="string" notnull="true" default="" loadInForm="true" uniquekey="system_name_lang">
    <cfproperty name="parents" singularname="parent" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="nodeHierarchy" inverse="true" weight="weight" clearBeforeSave="true">
    <cfproperty name="children" singularname="child" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="nodeHierarchy" inverse="true" orderby="weight asc">
    <cfproperty name="node" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="node" fkcolumn="nid">
    <cfproperty name="created" ormtype="timestamp" sqltype="timestamp">
    <cfproperty name="updated" ormtype="timestamp" sqltype="timestamp">
</cfcomponent>
```

**menu.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent entityname="menu" output="false" persistent="true" table="menus" extends="node" joincolumn="node_id" discriminatorvalue="menu">
    <cfproperty name="menuItems" singularname="menuItem" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="menuItem" inverse="true">
</cfcomponent>
```

**menuItem.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent entityname="menuItem" output="false" persistent="true" table="menus_items" extends="node" joincolumn="node_id" discriminatorvalue="menu_item">        
    <cfproperty name="menu" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="menu" fkcolumn="menu_id">
    <cfproperty name="parentMenuItem" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="menuItem" fkcolumn="menu_item_id">
    <cfproperty name="childMenuItems" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="menuItem" fkcolumn="menu_item_id">
    <cfproperty name="node" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="com.cfc.app.models.node" fkcolumn="nid">
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Have you tried `EntityReload()` to reload the entity data from the database?

Comment: Yes, I tried `<cfdump var="#oMenu.getMenuItems()#">` after removing the creating process and it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this `<cfset oMenuItem.setMenu( oMenu )>` AND `<cfset oMenu.addMenuItem( oMenuItem )>`.

It seems working now.

**index.cfm**

```
<cfset oMenu = entityNew( "menu" )>
<cfset oMenu.setTitle( "Main menu" )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenu )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfset oMenuItem = entityNew( "menuItem" )>
<cfset oMenuItem.setTitle( "First main menu item" )>
<cfset oMenuItem.setMenu( oMenu )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenuItem )>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfset oMenu.addMenuItem( oMenuItem )>
<cfset entitySave( oMenu)>
<cfset ORMFlush()>

<cfdump var="#oMenu.getMenuItems()#">
```

Comment: Have you tried this without the first two EntitySave() and EntityFlush()? Seems like you should only need to save once.

Comment: No, I can't because oMenu needs to have an ID to be added to oMenuItem.